# Can produce message with kafka-python, but can't with confluent-kafka

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python, confluent-kafka-python

I try to use `confluent-kafka`, but can't manage to send message to topic.
I did the same with `kafka-python`, and message sends.

What i am missing?

Thank you!

i use this code

```
# using confluent-kafka

from confluent_kafka import Producer

producer = Producer({
                    "bootstrap.servers": KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS,
                    "security.protocol": 'SASL_SSL',
                    "sasl.mechanism": 'SCRAM-SHA-512',
                    "sasl.username": secret_creds[KAFKA_VAULT_SECRET_USER_KEY],
                    "sasl.password": secret_creds[KAFKA_VAULT_SECRET_PASSWORD_KEY],
                    "ssl.ca.location": kafka_certificate_path,
                        })

for message in [bytes('confluent_{}'.format(num), 'utf-8') for num in range(10)]:
    producer.produce(topic=KAFKA_TOPIC_NAME, value=message)

producer.flush()

# using kaka-python

from kafka import KafkaProducer

producer_p = KafkaProducer(
    bootstrap_servers=KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS,
    security_protocol='SASL_SSL',
    sasl_mechanism='SCRAM-SHA-512',
    sasl_plain_username=secret_creds[KAFKA_VAULT_SECRET_USER_KEY],
    sasl_plain_password=secret_creds[KAFKA_VAULT_SECRET_PASSWORD_KEY],
        ssl_cafile=kafka_certificate_path,
    )

for message in [bytes('python_{}'.format(num), 'utf-8') for num in range(10)]:
    producer_p.send(KAFKA_TOPIC_NAME, message)

producer_p.flush()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was, that `kafka-python` accepts bootstrap servers as a list, e.g.

```
 [
'kafka1.dev.company.com:9094',
'kafka2.dev.company.com:9094',
'kafka3.dev.company.com:9094'
]
```

and `confluent-kafka` accepts that list as string:

```
'kafka1.dev.company.com:9094, kafka2.dev.company.com:9094, kafka3.dev.company.com:9094'
```